# Python3: using matplotlib to create figure, using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have got a dictionary in the form of `{test_size: (test_error, training_error)}`  Here it is:

```
{0.1: (0.94736842105263153, 0.90294117647058825), 0.2: (0.92105263157894735, 0.90397350993377479), 0.3: (0.82456140350877194, 0.9242424242424242), 0.6: (0.8722466960352423, 0.91390728476821192), 0.8: (0.76897689768976896, 0.98666666666666669), 0.5: (0.79894179894179895, 0.95767195767195767), 0.7: (0.8226415094339623, 0.99115044247787609), 0.9: (0.62463343108504399, 1.0), 0.4: (0.79605263157894735, 0.92920353982300885)}
```

I am trying to create a figure with `matplotlib` that looks like this:

[image: figure]

I would like to get the key of the dictionary (the test_size) on the x axis and the test and training error on the y axis.

How to solve this? Should I use a DataFrame?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
plt.plot(df)
???
```

I read things about that plotting dictionaries is only valuable using Python 2.. I am using Python 3 and I am really lost with this so far.. Hope anyone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this,

[image]

---

The source code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import operator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

d = {0.1: (0.94736842105263153, 0.90294117647058825), 0.2: (0.92105263157894735, 0.90397350993377479), 0.3: (0.82456140350877194, 0.9242424242424242), 0.6: (0.8722466960352423, 0.91390728476821192), 0.8: (0.76897689768976896, 0.98666666666666669), 0.5: (0.79894179894179895, 0.95767195767195767), 0.7: (0.8226415094339623, 0.99115044247787609), 0.9: (0.62463343108504399, 1.0), 0.4: (0.79605263157894735, 0.92920353982300885)}
lists = sorted(d.items())

x = list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), lists))
y = list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), lists))

y1 = list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), y))
ax.plot(x, y1, label='Test error', color='b', linewidth=2)

y2 = list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), y))
ax.plot(x, y2, label='Training error', color='r', linewidth=2)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks sparkandshine! Your code gives me this error unfortunately:TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'map'. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I think map is used in Python 2? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Papie, I use Python2. For Python3, try to replace `y1` with `list(y1)`.

Comment: thank you for your help! Unfortunately I still got an error:  list(y1) = map(operator.itemgetter(0), y)
                                             ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: @Sparkanshine, thanks it is almost working! I found out that the error that is left is that y2 = 0 in the code. y2 = list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), y))
It should be 9... I am trying to figure out how this is possible.

Comment: comment = ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension. Occuring in ---> 13 ax.plot(x, y2, label='training_error', color='r'). No idea why..

Comment: you are amazing!! I am so happy that it finally worked. Thank you so much!